# Can Inno Script contain 2 Groups?

Tags: inno-setup

How can i can a shortcut to a particular folder in  Start Menu?

Suppose Main Folder\Sub Folder\My Application is the hierarchy group in my current Inno Script. How can i create a short cut directly under Main Folder without changing DefaultGroupName

DefaultGroupName=Main Folder\Sub Folder\My Application

Comment: What do you mean by that *"Main Folder"* ? Do you mean the folder that the user chooses on the *Select Destination Location* wizard page ?

Comment: TLama.. Main Folder is the folder in Start Menu where i want to create some shortcuts without changing the group as explained above

Comment: Ok, well, what if the user deletes the proposed `Main Folder\Sub Folder\My Application` default group and decides to create the shortcuts somewhere else, e.g. `My Folder\My Sub` ? Do you want to reflect the change and create your additional shortcut in `My Folder` then ? And what if the user won't use subfolder in their change and use only `My Folder` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to say about 2 groups but if You want to create folder shortcut in start menu.You can do that by add the entry in start menu.If you want a special folder in start menu then you have to add the folder in `[Setup]` section with `DefaultGroupName`.You can also stop user from changing the folder by disabling program group page
(`DisableProgramGroupPage=yes`).

Look at the sample script,this will create a shortcut under `Activision\Call of Duty 2` in startmenu.

```
#define MyAppName "Call of Duty 2"
#define MyAppVersion "1.3"
#define MyAppPublisher "Activision"


[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={pf}\Activision\Call of Duty 2
//
DefaultGroupName=Activision\Call of Duty 2
//here you can change the folder in startmenu
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
UninstallDisplayName={#MyAppName}
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\Icon.ico


[Icons]
Name: {group}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}
Name: {group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}; Filename: {uninstallexe}
```

PS.I am using 'Call of Duty 2' example to make it more understandable.